# Redis cluster with leader-follower on Kubernetes and Spring-Boot configuration

Tags: spring-boot, redis, redis-cluster

I use this redis-operator: https://ot-container-kit.github.io/redis-operator/

Situation on Kubernetes after deploy:

```html
pod: redis-cluster-leader-0
pod: redis-cluster-follower-0
pod: redis-cluster-leader-1
pod: redis-cluster-follower-1
pod: redis-cluster-leader-2
pod: redis-cluster-follower-2
service: redis-cluster-leader
service: redis-cluster-follower
```

Now I'm not sure how I should configure this on Spring-Boot side. I've seen some answers saying I should list all nodes for `spring.redis.cluster.nodes` but it doesn't sound right to me, those services are there for a reason.

Possibilities I can think of:

1. `spring.redis.host=redis-cluster-leader` - doesn't work, `io.lettuce.core.RedisCommandExecutionException: MOVED 13927 10.54.37.8:6379`
2. `spring.redis.cluster.nodes=redis-cluster-leader:6379,redis-cluster-follower:6379` - it works, but I'm not sure it's correct, I have `errorstat_NOAUTH:count=1` and `errorstat_MOVED:count=1` when I do `INFO` in `redis-cli` (they are password protected)
3. listing all 6 nodes for `spring.redis.cluster.nodes`, definitely feels wrong to me

Option 2 works, but I'm not sure, mostly because of the `errorstat`. Also this configuration is clearly meant to list the nodes, but I'm not listing the nodes, just services. Spring thinks there are 2 nodes when there are in fact 6 nodes, not sure if it has any consequences.

When I randomly killed some pods (not all of them) it just stopped working with tons of errors on the application side - no route no host, timeouts etc.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the headless service which the operator also creates? This made it work for me.

```
spring.redis.host=redis-cluster-leader-headless
```

Comment: Ye, I tried, it helped, but in the end it still didn't work as I wanted, used spotahome operator - different pattern, but still enough for me.